# Rails flash messages doesn't show

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm out... 3 hours and still nothing. I made before_filter for my app in application_controller.rb:

```
def fill_profile

unless current_user.profile.state_id.present?
  flash[:add_state] = 'add_state'
  return respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to edit_profile_path(current_user.profile) }
  end
end
end
```

And now, assets_controller.rb:

```
class AssetsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :fill_profile

end
```

index action in assets_controller is empty. I press link:

```
<%= link_to 'abc', assets_path %>
```

and nothing... there is no flash message. For every other controller this before_filter works, only for assets_controller doesn't. Can somebody help?

There is no redirect except this one in before_filter. When i put only flash message in before_filter without redirect_to - it works even for assets_controller.

i have also exacly that same link for messages:

```
<%= link_to 'def', messages_path %>
```

and exacly that same empty messages_controller.rb with only before_filter - AND IT WORK!

View for flash messages:

```
<div id="flash_messages">
  <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <%= render :partial => 'shared/flash_element', :locals => { :key => key.to_s.downcase, :value => value } %>
   <% end %>
 </div>
```

Comment: Are you showing the flash in your layout file? Are you using the same layout as in the other controllers?

Comment: Can you post how you are printing out your flash message?

Comment: Yes, i have that same view in wrapper div for every page. Everywere flash works, only not for assets_controller. But it doesn't mater how i render it in view. Eveny <%= flash[:add_state] %> doesn't show flash only for assets_controller. I delete everything from project. There is no other controller only messages and assets. For messages i see flash, for assets don't.

Comment: NOW im very surprised. I open my old project with that same kind of flash messages. And there also that type of before_filter doesnt work only for assets_controller. It doesnt metter if index.html.erb is empty or not. Doesn't meter if def index in controller is empty or not. Flash just doesnt work :)

Comment: paperclip can be a problem and fact, that asset has attached file?